# The Performance Consequences of Parameterizing Constants in PreparedStatement Queries

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

When using **JDBC's PreparedStatements** to query **Oracle**, consider this:

```
String qry1 = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE rownum=? AND col2=?";

String qry2 = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE rownum=1 AND col2=?";

String qry3 = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE rownum=1 AND col2=" + someVariable ;
```

The logic dictates that **the value of rownum is always a constant** (1 in this example). While **the value of col2 is a changing variable**.

***Question 1:*** Are there any Oracle server performance advantages (query compilation, caching, etc.) to using qry1 where rownum value is parameterized, over qry2 where rownum's constant value is hardcoded?

***Question 2:*** Ignoring non-performance considerations (such as SQL Injections, readability, etc.), are there any Oracle server performance advantages (query compilation, caching, etc.) to using qry2 over qry3 (in which the value of col2 is explicitly *appended*, not parameterized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1:** *There are no performance advantages to using qry1 (a softcoded query) over qry2 (a query with reasonable bind variables).*

Bind variables improve performance by reducing query parsing; if the bind variable is a constant there is no extra parsing to avoid.

(There are probably some weird examples where adding extra bind variables improves the performance of one specific query.  Like with any forecasting program, occasionally if you feed bad information to the Oracle optimizer the result will be better.  But it's important to understand that those are exceptional cases.)

**Answer 2:** *There are many performance advantages to using qry2 (a query with reasonable bind variables) over qry3 (a hardcoded query).*

Bind variables allow Oracle re-use a lot of the work that goes into query parsing (query compilation).  For example, for each query Oracle needs to check that the user has access to view the relevant tables.  With bind variables that work only needs to be done once for all executions of the query.

Bind variables also allow Oracle to use some extra optimization tricks that only occur after the Nth run.  For example, Oracle can use cardinality feedback to improve the second execution of a query.  When Oracle makes a mistake in a plan, for example if it estimates a join will produce 1 row when it really produces 1 million, it can sometimes record that mistake and use that information to improve the next run.  Without bind variables the next run will be different and it won't be able to fix that
 mistake.

Bind variables also allow for many different plan management features.  Sometimes a DBA needs to change an execution plan without changing the text of the query.  Features like SQL plan baselines, profiles, outlines, and DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE will not work if the query text is constantly changing.

On the other hand, there are a few reasonable cases where it's better to hard-code the queries.  Occasionally an Oracle feature like partition pruning cannot understand the expression and it helps to hardcode the value.  For large data warehouse queries the extra time to parse a query may be worth it if the query is going to run for a long time anyway.

(Caching is unlikely to affect either scenario.  Result caching of a statement is rare, it's much more likely that Oracle will cache only the blocks of the tables used in the statement.  The buffer cache probably does not care if those blocks are accessed by one statement many times or by many statements one time)